# Facebook sdk for Unity: error

Tags: unityscript, facebook-unity-sdk

As facebook just released it's new sdk for Unity. I m trying to use FB.API method and getting a lot of troubles with it. Like this is code I have written in UnityScript in my Unity project.

```
function LoginCallback() {
    Debug.Log("User id is"+ FB.UserId);
    FB.API("/me?fields=id,first_name,friends.limit(100).fields(first_name,id)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, LogCallback, null);
    FBUtil.Log(FB.UserId); // Use this to sync progress, etc.
}

function LogCallback(response:String) {
//    Debug.Log(response);
    var profile = FBUtil.DeserializeJSONProfile(response);
    var friends = FBUtil.DeserializeJSONFriends(response);
}
```

I am getting this error in Unity Log
 BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'FBUtil'.
And if I comment out the FBUtil part and just try to print the json string by writing this

```
function LoginCallback() {
    Debug.Log("User id is"+ FB.UserId);
    FB.API("/me?fields=id,first_name,friends.limit(100).fields(first_name,id)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, LogCallback, null);

}

function LogCallback(response:String) {
    Debug.Log(response);
        }
```

I am able to get Fb.UserId but I am not getting the response with the following details like first_name, friends. The error in DDMS Log is this

"09-04 21:35:04.534: E/Unity(23893): (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 54)
"

Someone help me out.

Comment: Hi Rohit,

Sorry, we messed up the asset store upload and an incomplete sample game ended up there. Still waiting for Unity to approve a new version without that, in the meantime I've put the classes here:
http://snipplr.com/view/72269/fbutilcs/ http://snipplr.com/view/72268/gamestatemanagercs/

For your second problem, can you paste more of the error? This line is inside the Unity engine itselff

Comment: @aaron thanks for the files! 1st error have been removed.
On the second error..
I call the FB API and then I am trying to get the response but the problem is response is never getting printed in DDMS log and all I am getting is  (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 54) "
    Debug.Log(response);
should print the jsonString right? But jsonString is not getting printed

Comment: @aaron this time I put this in Debug
    function LogCallback(response:String) {
 Debug.Log("response"+response);
    }
And I got this in Log
09-05 14:23:22.880: I/Unity(12131): response����

I don't know if it helps or not.

Comment: Hi Rohit, can you show me the call you're making too? Your response looks like binary data, are you getting the profile picture for example?  the FB.API call doesn't currently support anything but a string result, we're working on a solution though. (if you have a code project you'd like to point me at I'd be glad to take a look)

Comment: @aaron I am getting the profile picture url if I parse the response. Like if I do this

    var profile = JSON.Parse(response);
 var url = profile["picture"]["data"]["url"].Value;
 Debug.Log("Picture url is"+url);

But if I try to debug response got from the callback delegate I got the above mentioned result. Anyways my issue is solved as I am able to get the profile picture url. Thanks! :)